# Display any base64 image with unknown content type

Tags: html, data-uri

I have a base64 encoded version of an image (say, a png) which I want to display on my page. Normally, I would just do `data:image/png;base64,<base64 string>`; however, I don't know the content type of the image, ie. it could be a PNG, JPEG, GIF,...; I only know that it is some kind of image.

Chrome and firefox accept the image if I just always use `image/png`, but that seems kinda hacky; is there another way to tell the browser to just take whatever it gets?

Answer (score 0):

I would try "image" and "image/*" despite their being nonstandard.